# How do you process the output of a command in the shell line-by-line?

Tags: shell

I need to process the shared library dependencies of a library from a bash script. The `for` command processes word-by-word:

```
for DEPENDENCY in `otool -L MyApplication | sed 1d`
do
    ...
done
```

What is the way to process the results line-by-line?

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You should use the `read` command.

```
otool -L MyApplication | sed 1d | \
while read i
do
  echo "line: " $i
done
```

See [bashref](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-read-142) for a description of the read builtin, and its options. You can also have a look at the following [tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sh.html#uh-78) for examples of using `read` in conjunction with `for`.

Comment: Warning: if you need to set variables in the while loop (i.e. store what you found in otool's output), they'll vanish as soon as the loop exits because it's part of a pipeline and therefore runs in a subshell.  In bash, you can get around this with a bit of rearranging: `while read i; do ... done < <(otool -L MyApplication | sed 1d)`

Comment: Another warning: This will delete a lot of spaces and backslashes. Use `read -r i` to read lines without such modifications.

Comment: @Jens, no, it's the echo command eating spaces. `echo "line: $i"` will prevent that.

Comment: @JamesMorris No, it's the read that eats leading and trailing whitespace and backslashes. Try `printf '     foo\\bar  \n'|read a; echo "<$a>"` and then with `read -r`.

Comment: @Jens, read the man page, nowhere does it mention whitespace. the `-r` option simply prevents special treatment of backslashes.

Comment: Why is it that I have exclude the first line with this answer? (sed 1d).   I'm noticing if I exclude '1d' it spits back the sed help page (command fails to run).

Comment: @jersey-bean `otool` output consists in a first line with the name of the library followed by `:`. Then you have the dependencies, one per line.So we strip the first line since the original question was about iterating over dependencies.

Comment: @Jens, ...it's the act of clearing `IFS` in the best-practice invocation of `IFS= read -r i` that eliminates leading and trailing whitespace pruning.

Comment: @JamesMorris, jens *was* actually correct that leading and trailing whitespace gets pruned, just incorrect about what to do about it. This is covered in more detail in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: And in bash, the test demonstrating all these differences needs to be more like `printf ' foo\\bar \n' | { IFS= read -r a; echo "<$a>"; }`; without explicit grouping, the `echo` doesn't run in the same subshell that was spawned as part of the pipeline ([BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)).

Comment: BTW, `echo "line: " $i` would be less buggy if written as `echo "line: $i"`, or even `echo line: "$i"`. It's important to quote the parameter expansion; it's not important to quote the constant string (that doesn't have any content that might cause it to be incorrectly interpreted as shell syntax).

Comment: Also, it'd be a slight efficiency improvement to replace `sed 1d | ...` with `{ read _; while IFS= read -r i; do echo "line: $i"; done; }` -- that way we don't have an extra executable in our pipeline needing to be started up and then loop over the whole data stream, but just have bash itself read the header into `_`, thus throwing it away, before diving into the loop.

Answer (score 10):

```
otool -L MyApplication | sed 1d | while read line ;
do
  # do stuff with $line
done
```

Comment: Should be `while IFS= read -r line` to avoid munging leading/trailing whitespace or backslashes. See [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the Internal Field Separator to a newline. By default, bash is going to separate tokens by spaces when using a for loop. Your IFS setting will make the for loop split up the tokens based on whatever string IFS is equal to (thus splitting up the list tokens by newlines instead of by tokens by spaces).

```
[bash ] $ IFS="
"
[bash ] $ for DEPENDENCY in `otool -L MyApplication | sed 1d`
do
    ....
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use shell builtin `read`, but be careful with lines containing spaces and tabs. I suggest locally change value of `$IFS`:

```
 otool -L MyApplication | sed 1d | \
 while IFS= read i; do
     echo "line: $i"
 done
```

[Edit: applied Charles' suggestion]

Comment: You're currently changing `IFS` only for the `read`, but leaving it at its prior/default value for the unquoted expansion. Move `$i` in the `echo` into quotes (`echo "line: $i"`) to avoid string-splitting and glob expansion. See also [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Answer (score 1):

The modern bash way:

```
while read i; do
    ...
done < <(otool -L MyApplication | sed 1d)
```

Note: the two "<"s above is not a typo, that's the correct syntax.

Comment: `while IFS= read -r i; do` -- if you don't clear IFS, leading and trailing whitespace is removed; if you don't use `-r`, backslashes are interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` to process things on a per-line basis. Exactly what's the best way depends on what you're trying to do though.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it awk as well. No need to use a bash for loop

```
otool -L MyApplication | awk 'NR>1
{
  # do your stuff here since awk process line by line.
}'
```