# list in script shell bash

Tags: bash, list, shell

I did this script

```
#!/bin/bash

liste=`ls -l`
for i in $liste
do
    echo $i
done
```

The problem is I want the script displays each result line by line, but it displays word by word :

I have :

```
my_name
etud 
4096
Oct
8
10:13
```

and I want to have :

```
my_name etud 4096 Oct 8 10:13
```

The final aim of the script is to analyze each line ; it is the reason I want to be able to recover the entire line. Maybe the list is not the best solution but I don't know how to recover the lines.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you process the output of a command in the shell line-by-line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113005/how-do-you-process-the-output-of-a-command-in-the-shell-line-by-line)

Comment: @federem Why don't you tell us what _specific_ information you want from the line? Timestamp? Size? There are better ways to get those things, not involving `ls`.

Answer (score 1):

To start, we'll assume that none of your filenames ever contain newlines:

```
ls -l | IFS= while read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
    # Do whatever else you want with $line
done
```

If your filenames *could* contain newlines, things get tricky. In this case, it's better (although slower) to use `stat` to retrieve the desired metadata from each file individually. Consult `man stat` for details about how your local variety of `stat` works, as it is unfortunately not very standardized.

```
for f in *; do
    line=$(stat -c "%U %n %s %y" "$f")  # One possibility
    # Work with $line as if it came from ls -l
done
```

Comment: True. If you have to run a new process for each file anyway, though, the control over the output that `stat` allows may be more convenient. (But yeah, I simply overlooked that you could call `ls` for each file.)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace

```
echo $i
```

with

```
echo -n "$i "
```

echo -n outputs to console without newline.

Comment: `echo -n` is not POSIX standard. `printf` is the safe, portable approach.

Comment: @Charles Duffy, it is defined in IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 POSIX.

Comment: @JimBlack Only as an XSI extension.

Comment: @JimBlack quote: "The System V echo **does not support any options,** but allows escape sequences within its operands, as described for XSI implementations in the OPERANDS section." Another quote: "It is not possible to use echo portably across all POSIX systems unless both -n (as the first argument) and escape sequences are omitted."

Answer (score 0):

Another to do it with a while loop and without a pipe:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    echo "line: $line"
done < <(ls -l)
```

Comment: This is correct (except for using `read` without `-r` -- thus having escape sequences interpreted -- and leaving `$IFS` at defaults -- and thus having trailing whitespace stripped), if the goal is to demonstrate reading from a stream. It's incorrect, if the goal is to demonstrate reading a list of files (some people really do think that `ls` is the right way to do this!). It would be good for an answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

First, I hope that you aren't genuinely using `ls` in your real code, but only using it as an example. If you want a list of files, `ls` is the wrong tool; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for details.

Second, modern versions of bash have a builtin called `readarray`.

Try this:

```
readarray -t my_array < <(ls -l)
for entry in "${my_array[@]}"; do
  read -a pieces <<<"$entry"
  printf '<%s> ' "${pieces[@]}"; echo
done
```

First, it creates an array (called `my_array`) with all the output from the command being run.

Then, for each line in that output, it creates an array called  `pieces`, and emits each piece with arrow brackets around them.

If you want to read a line at a time, rather than reading the entire file at once, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 ("How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?")

Comment: `<(ls -l)` will fail under the same circumstances as `ls -l | while read...`.

Comment: @chepner If your meaning is `ls`-specific, I don't believe I ever implied anything to the contrary -- see the first paragraph of my answer. (That said, unless you don't consider losing any process-local state relating to the content you've read "failing", I can't agree with the accuracy of the objection in the general, non-ls-specific case)

Answer (score 0):

Joinning the previous answers with the need to store the list of files in a variable. You can do this

```
echo -n "$list"|while read -r lin
do
 echo $lin
done
```